# Hibernate mapping collection inside container entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following class structure:

```
public class Container {

    private Set<Child> childs  = new HashSet<>();
}

public class Child {

    String name;
    String value;
    String param;
}
```

Because of Container class is going to be single in application (just wrapper on collections that may be updated), I would like to store it in single table, e.g."childs" with columns

```
id | name | value | param
```

Is it possible to make such mapping in order to use Container when fetch or
store it through hb session with corresponding updates to childs collection:

```
getSession().saveOrUpdate(container)
```

And if so, what mapping should be in that case?

UPD: I was going to have 2 classes mapped to single table

Comment: What you are willing to achieve is to update all the Child element at once, in one operation ?

Comment: Yes, I wrapped them in a container class and also would like to use the single table to store data.

Can it be one table with fields `container_id | child_id | name | value | param` ?

Comment: Do you have a separated table "Container" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I ended up with such solution:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "childs")
public class Container {

    @Id
    //optional your id strategy
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "xyz")
    Long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name="childs", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
    private Set<Child> childs  = new HashSet<>();
}

@Embeddable
public class Child {

    String name;
    String value;
    String param;
}
```

table structure - `childs(id, name, value, param)`

Answer (score 0):

im not sure about the getSession().saveOrUpdate(container) , but the mapping for you problem should look something like this.

```
    @Entity
    public class Container {
        @ManyToOne
        private Set<Child> childs  = new HashSet<>();
    }
    @Entity
    public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        Long id;
        String name;
        String value;
        String param;
    }
```